# Python in two different directories( one specified and one hidden)

Tags: python, pandas, pip

After installing Python I have it located in two different directories. One is visible which is the installing path I chose during installation and the second one is hidden (C:Users\username....).

I have now problem using pandas because the program is working in the hidden directory. Is it possible to change the working directory somehow. I am using Python IDLE to run my python scripts.

I get this message when I run my scripts with pandas:

> module 'pandas' from 'C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py

Answer (score 3):

Please change your Python path from the IDLE

Comment: could you tell me how to do it? You cannot do it from FIle/Path Browser

Comment: Hey, there, you are using Windows I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the path from the current cmd window using the PATH = command. That will only add it for the current cmd instance. if you want to add it permanently, you should add it to system variables.

```
Computer > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables
```

You would goto your `cmd` instance, and put in:

```
PATH = C:/Python3/
```

Check the folder name for Python in you C drive and edit the above appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the answer supplied by jwpfox, if you are using Python 2.7/3.6 mainly for research/fun purposes I would suggest uninstalling all Python versions and packages and installing an easy to use package manager. For example [conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html) package manager, which is installed automatically with [Anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html).

I would not advice using Anaconda if you are actively developing software applications with Python. But apart from hardcore coding, it is a very useful tool and with plenty of sources for support online.

Tiz